# Python Mathplotlib Selecting Values and Removing via Rectangle Selection

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, point

The comparison below gives me an error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". I also dont know how to remove elements in array that are within a range of min and max. (given I import numpy as np)

```
 if self.datax > selected_min and self.datax < selected_max:
            self.datax = np.arange[self.datax - VALUES BETWEEN MIN AND MAX]
            print(self.datax)
            plt.plot(self.datax,self.datay)
```

ie. Lets say I have an array named xvalues containing 21,52,3,34,5,16,47,98,9,130
How would I remove numbers between 30 and 60 from the array so it now contains 21,3,5,16,98,9,130?

I came up with the following which now removes the values selected from the data but with an error of .00001 and also the plot doesnt update to those new values.

```
temp_select = self.genx[1:3]
print(temp_select)
#self.genx = list(set(self.genx)-set(temp_select))
self.genx = [ item for item in self.genx if not sel_min < item < sel_max ]
print(self.genx)
plt.plot(self.genx,self.geny)
```

Comment: I am not strictly clear what your question is.  Have you read http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html ?

Comment: Hello there. I have updated the question above so hopefully its more clear now and yes I have looked at the event handlers. What I want to figure out now is how to remove the values selected by the drawn rectangle and redraw the plot to show the result when the values are deleted. What I have so far is at the end of on_release I would check for the conditions within the boundaries of the rectangle. In this case for x-values the left border of the rectangle(min) and right border(max) are used to determine which values to remove from genx (generated x values).

Comment: But what is your question?  You have a list of requirements and a bunch of code.  What is it doing that you don't expect or not doing that you do expect?  What specific parts of the process are you stuck on?  Can you make the code more concise to include _just_ the part you are having trouble with?

Comment: What I cant seem to figure out is how to do a boolean comparison to check if the data that is selected are contained within that rectangle. Am I doing the boolean correctly? Also how would I remove the selected datax, specified by min and max?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.BboxBase.contains Use something like this function to determine which points are in the box.